# How is the chord length defined if the wing (whale flipper) is tapering like a wing and has a twist throughout the span?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil

Let me be more specific:

1. I have a 3D scan of a whale tubercle.
2. The tubercle is tapering and twisting along its half span.
3. I want to find the mean chord length.
   [image]
   Now let us say that my airfoil section is at 10 degrees. So how is the chord length defined?

a) is it a line that directly joins the LE and the TE (chord length has a slant)
b) is it the line joining the projection of the LE and TE on a flat plane ( slope of chord line =0)

Comment: Which f̶l̶a̶t̶ (every plane is flat) plane would you want to use? The aircraft reference datum is rather arbitrary and the relative wind changes with speed and wing loading.

Comment: Just added a picture in the question... so up here in the picture, the chord length is defined as '**a straight line joining the LE to TE**' but book claim it to be '**the chord is simply the size of the wing in streamwise direction**'

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because the referenced question doesn't answer how to deal with variable twist when calculating the mean chord ("3. I want to find the mean chord length"). The question "Is $S=\int c(y) dx$ or is it the projected surface on a certain plane ($S=\int c(y)\cdot cos(\alpha_i(y)) dx$, with $\alpha_i$ the incidence angle)?" isn't answered there. @AdityaKulkarni You'll probably have to pick a definition yourself. I'd choose a plane which minimizes incidence angles along the span and calculate the projected surface on it. For the mean chord $MC=\frac{S}{Span}$.